# Powershell - remove all blobs in a container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I need to remove all of the blobs in a specific container before doing a backup to that container.  The following does not work.  What is the proper way to do this?

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx |  Remove-AzStorageBlob -DeleteSnapshot -Force
```

I get the following error message for each blob returned by Get-AzStorageBlob:

```
Remove-AzStorageBlob : The specified blob does not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified blob does not exist.
ErrorCode: BlobNotFound
ErrorMessage: The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:eb2612f4-f01e-0067-5471-3e9f69000000
Time:2019-07-19T20:33:50.1261168Z
At line:15 char:62
+ ... inerName -Context $ctx |  Remove-AzStorageBlob -DeleteSnapshot -Force
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzStorageBlob], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.RemoveStorageAzureBlobCommand
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by “does not work”? Are none of the blobs deleted or just some of the blobs deleted?

Comment: Would it be simpler to delete and recreate the storage container?

Comment: I don't think I can delete it unless it's empty.  Also, I don't see any reason this shouldn't work and that bugs me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test with your ps script, it's caused by the `-DeleteSnapshot -Force`, delete it and then it works well.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

[image]

And if you want to delete snapshot, just add `-Force`. Here is the [Parameters description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/remove-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-6.13.0#parameters), `-Force` indicates that this cmdlet removes the blob and its snapshot without confirmation.

You could have a try, hope this could help you.

Note: If you are using the newer [Az Module,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-8.1.0) the above code will look like:

`Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx | Remove-AzStorageBlob`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `Remove-AzStorageBlob` can delete blobs in bulk, so you will have to loop through the blobs you get returned from `Get-AzureStorageBlob`.

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Remove-AzureStorageBlob   # or: Remove-AzureStorageBlob -ICloudBlob $_.ICloudBlob -Context $ctx
}
```